# Accessing LDAP from an android app written using .net maui

Tags: android, ldap, maui

I am trying to access LDAP for authentication from an android Maui App.  I do not want to use Azure Active Directory to do this so MSAL is not an option.  Has anyone done this.

The java libraries that I have tried will not compile with Maui.